# Azure Developer Admin Account Blocked after Testing Identity Risk Events

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Yesterday I was triggering Identity Risk Events so I could test the downloading the Audit Log entries using Microsoft's GraphServiceClient API through a dev Azure Active Directory account.  Using Tor Browser I was able to complete that task however today when attempted to login to my Azure Dev Account it said I was locked out. I am still able to pull the logs however I can't login to unlock my own dev account.  The risky behavior test was executed over 16 hours ago yet my account is still locked out and since I can't get in the dev account appears to be permanently locked and therefor totally useless.  I can't even create a support ticket because I can't login.  If I try to create a support ticket using my prod Azure account I can't because the dev account is not linked with my prod account.  Any idea how I can login so I can use my dev account again?

Answer (score 0):

If your Azure AD tenant has smart lockout policies configured, your account will remain locked out for the duration specified in those policies and even the administrator must wait for the duration to expire. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-smart-lockout

However, you should be able to unlock yourself by using self-service password reset (SSPR) from a trusted device or location if you have your account set up for SSPR.

If you have already waited for the duration, the account is still blocked, and you are the only admin on the tenant, you can reach out to the Azure Data Protection team to get help. Their number is 866-807-5850.